# TClientDataset: Is there a way to make a StringField behave like an IntegerField when setting an index?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to sort a **ClientDataset** by a **StringField** which contains Integers. These Integers are used as item numbers on invoices. When I sort the ClientDataset by that field using a simple index the result is this:

1
10
100
101
11
110
111
12
120

However I'd like them to be sorted like an **IntegerField**:

1
10
11
12
100
101
110
111
120

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: This would seem to be more to do with database than Delphi.

Comment: @Dsm It's quite a big chunk of data and the user can sort the ClientDataset at runtime by any of the key columns... So it would be inconvenient to rerun the query whenever the user changes the index.. :/

Comment: Is there a reason to not just change the field type then? All data is Integer, you want it to be sorted like Integer?

Comment: @NilsBremer That is kind of irrelevant. Under the covers a new query will be run anyway, surely. It doesn't just sort the data retrieved from the database so far. If you are using a temporary table to store your data (or even if not) then a calculated field might be the answer, but no matter what you will need a new index, which is why I say more DB than Delphi.

Comment: @nil Well it's pretty old and dirty code (evolved over time, you know the deal...) that I didn't write.. So I don't know if changing the field type will have any negative consequences. I'll try to change it and see what happens :)

Comment: @nil Right so I did what [MartynA suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062409/9013441) and it works nicely. I decided not to change the field type, because the field is being used in a lot of other places as well.. (don't want to make the mess worse than it already is :D)

Comment: Sure, I just asked because that would have been the obvious first question I'd asked myself. And I realize that at times the answer cannot be "sure, I'll make the fundamental change with unknown side effects". ;) @MartynA's answer is indeed elegant and save in this regard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to change your existing field to a different type.  Instead, a way to do what you want is to define an ftInteger field on the CDS which is of FieldFind fkInternalCalc.  Then in the CDS's OnCalcFields event, set the field's value by converting the value of your string field to an integer.

The point of setting the calculated field's find tp fkInternalCalc is that the CDS can be indexed on, and hence sorted by, an fkInternalCalc field, unlike an fkCalculated field. So, by indexing your CDS on the added fkInternalCalc field, the records should be appear in their numeric order rather that the alphanumeric order of your string field.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.CDS1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if CDS1IntField.IsNull then
    CDS1IntField.AsInteger := StrToInt(CDS1StringField.AsString);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  for i := 1 to 100 do
    CDS1.InsertRecord([IntToStr(i)]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CDS1.IndexFieldNames := 'IntField';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy solution, works nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort as integers: by far the best approach is to: change the type to integer.

Yes, it's more work, but *hear me out*.

---

Currently you have 2 possibilities: either all your values are currently *canonical<sup>1</sup> integers*, or they are not.

If they are, then you do have a little work to do. You need to change:

- The column in the database
- Any foreign key columns containing the same data
- The types of any persisted fields for those columns
- Any code that is expecting string item numbers

And you'll gain the following benefits:

- Better performance due to: single op comparisons, less data in memory, narrower keys for B-Tree indexes and reduced heap memory allocations in Delphi for the previous long string objects.
- Less concern about the nuances of strings and string comparison. E.g. unexpected padding.
- And a strong typing guarantee that you'll not unexpectedly have to deal with 'problematic strings'. You raised a concern whether you would "have any negative consequences" due to making the change. I'm not aware of any. *However, not making the change **does** risk the consequence of unexpected non-integer item numbers.*

---

However, if your item numbers are **not canonical integers**: then trying to sort as integers is already problematic. How would you sort the following item numbers as integers?

```
'03', '13', '3', 'B2', '  13 ', '3bad'
```

[Martyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062409/224704) would be the best way to go in this situation. Because you retain the original string value, you still have a safe and reliable key. (NB only use the internal calc field for sorting).

Note, you would have to tweak the: `CDS1IntField.AsInteger := StrToInt(CDS1StringField.AsString);` line to ensure you can set sensible sorting values. Any exceptions raised due to failure to convert some string would lead to nasty problems.

As a bonus, Martyn's answer is safe in the short term before you've investigated the knock-on effects of the larger change. But you may want to schedule time for the 'big job'.

---

<sup>1</sup> The point about '*canonical*' integers is subtle but important. Prefixing any number of zero's or spaces to an integer produces a *non-canonical* duplicate. Consider "3" and "03". As integers they are the same, but as strings they are different.

Comment: I agree with most of that, except "And a strong typing guarantee ..."  Hardly, what about SqlLite databases, where the defined column type in the db is no guarantee of what it actually contains?

Comment: First of all thanks for explaining :) According to your explanation we have mostly non canonical integers in our ancient database.. :/ So I think for short term I'm going with Martyn's answer.

Comment: @MartynA Yes, some DBMSes may lack the necessary type safety. But anything that can be done to guarantee type safety reduces concern about inconsistencies. Also, afaik SqLite does enforce integer PK. And I suspect it may be possible to add a CHECK constraint to ensure values can be stored as integers.

Comment: @NilsBremer It sounds like your DB is a practical example of the long term consequences of loose data types. Martyn's answer is a good choice.